# How do I discriminate two different type of abnormalities in curvature of the object?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have been working on a project that require finding defect in onions. The second image that's attached shows an abnormal onion. You can see that the onion is made-up of two smaller onion twins. What's interesting is that human eye can easily detect whats wrong with the structure.

One can do an structural analysis and can observe that a normal onion has almost smooth curvature while an abnormal one doesn't. Thus quite simply I want to build a classification algorithm based on the edges of the object.

However there are times when the skin of onion makes the curve irregular. See the image, there's a small part of skin that's outside the actual curvature. I want to discriminate the bulged part due to the skin vs the deformities produced at the point where the two subsection meet and then reconstruct the contour of object for further analysis .

Is there a mathematical thing that would help me here given the fact that I have majority of the points that makes the outer edge of onion including the two irregularities?

[image: Healthy onion with deformity bulging out]
[[image: Another deformed image[2]]

See the code below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import sys

cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)


cv2.namedWindow('test', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow('orig', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow('test', 600,600)
cv2.resizeWindow('orig', 600,600)





image = cv2.imread('./buffer/crp'+str(sys.argv[1])+'.JPG')

tim = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hsv_image =  cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
frame_threshed = cv2.inRange(hsv_image, np.array([70,0,0],np.uint8), 
                np.array([140,255,255],np.uint8))

canvas = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)
framhreshed=cv2.threshold(frame_threshed,10,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
frame_threshed = cv2.erode(frame_threshed,kernel,iterations = 1)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
frame_threshed = cv2.erode(frame_threshed,kernel,iterations = 1)
kernel = np.ones((7,7),np.uint8)
frame_threshed = cv2.erode(frame_threshed,kernel,iterations = 1)

_, cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(frame_threshed.copy(), 
cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts= sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

big_contours = [c for c in cnts if cv2.contourArea(c) > 100000]

for cnt in big_contours:
perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
epsilon = 0.0015*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,epsilon,True)
# print(len(approx))
hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt,returnPoints = False)
# try:
defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt,hull)
for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
    s,e,f,d = defects[i,0]
    start = tuple(cnt[s][0])
    end = tuple(cnt[e][0])
    far = tuple(cnt[f][0])
    cv2.line(canvas,start,end,[255,0,0],2)
    cv2.circle(canvas,far,5,[255,255,255],-1)

cv2.drawContours(image, [approx], -1, (0, 0, 255), 5)
cv2.drawContours(canvas, [approx], -1, (0, 0, 255), 5)



cv2.imshow('orig',image)
cv2.imshow('test',canvas)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to try HuMoments since you already have extracted the shape of your objects. It would allow you to calculate a distance between two shapes, so basically between your abnormal onion and a reference onion.

The Hu Moments shape descriptor is available for Python using OpenCV. If `image` is binary, you can use it like this :

```
# Reference image
shapeArray1 = cv2.HuMoments(cv2.moments(image1)).flatten()
# Abnormal image
shapeArray2 = cv2.HuMoments(cv2.moments(image2)).flatten()
# Calculation of distance between both arrays
# Threshold based on the distancce
# Classification as abnormal or normal
```

MatchShapes could do the job too. It takes two binary images of contours to return a float that evaluate the distance between both.

Python: cv.MatchShapes(object1, object2, method, parameter=0) → float

[More details](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?)

So when an onion shape is detected as abnormal, you would have to fill this shape and apply some [binary morphology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology#Basic_operators) to erase the imperfection and extract the shape without imperfection.

1. Fill your shape
2. Apply an opening (erosion followed by dilatation) with a disk structural element to get rid of the irregularities
3. Extract the contours again
4. You should have a form without your irregularities. If not, go back to step 2 and change the size of the structural element

Comment: Will it help me to detect the bulges due dry leaves that tend to be outwards?

Comment: @NikhilPandey It would help you detect the fact that your onion is not perfectly shaped (distance much more important). But it will not tell you where the defects are, that is the next step. Let me edit my answer to help you with the detection part.

Answer (score 3):

OK so if you look at the first two pictures of your onions you can see that they have a circular shape (except the peel peaks) and the "defect" one has more of an oval shape. What you could try is to find your contour (after you apply image transformation of course) and determine its center points. Then you could measure the distance from the center of the contour to each point of the contour. You can do it using scipy (`ckd.tree()` and `tree.query()`) or simply by mathematical formula for distance between two points `sqrt(x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2`. Then you can say that if some number of points are out of bounds it is still an OK onion but if there are a lot of points out of bounds then it is a defective onion. I drew two example images just for the sake of demonstration.

Example in code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import spatial


img = cv2.imread('oniond.png')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_image,180,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
im2, cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
list_distance = []
points_minmax = []

M = cv2.moments(cnt)
cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
center = (cX, cY)

for i in cnt:
    tree = spatial.cKDTree(i)
    mindist, minid = tree.query(center)
    list_distance.append(mindist)
    if float(mindist) < 100:
        points_minmax.append(i)
    elif float(mindist) > 140:
        points_minmax.append(i)
    else:
        pass

reshape = np.reshape(list_distance, (-1,1))

under_min = [i for i in list_distance if i < 100]
over_max = [i for i in list_distance if i > 140]

for i in points_minmax:
    cv2.line(img,center,(i[0,0],i[0,1]),(0,0,255),2)

if len(over_max) > 50:
    print('defect')
    print('distances over maximum: ', len(over_max))
    print('distances over minimum: ', len(under_min ))

elif len(under_min ) > 50:
    print('defect')
    print('distances over maximum: ', len(over_max))
    print('distances over minimum: ', len(under_min ))

else:
    print('OK')
    print('distances over maximum: ', len(over_max))
    print('distances over minimum: ', len(under_min ))

cv2.imshow('img', img)
```

Result:

[image]

OK

distances over maximum:  37

distance over minimum:  0

The output shows that there are 37 points out of bounds (red color) but the onion is still OK.

Result 2:

[image]

defect

distances over maximum:  553

distances over minimum:  13

And here you can see that there are more points out of bounds (red color) and the onion is not OK.

Hope this gives at least an idea on how to solve your problem. Cheers!

Comment: Great intuition. I had similar thing in my mind. However, there's a constraint that the top view is not the only view that will be processed. Imagine trowing a bucket full of as such on floor. Now I think the side-on projection of an onion is a challenge remain to be addressed. What do you think?

Comment: Hey! Yes ofcorse the side of processing is an issue...if someone would want to make a vision inspection of such products you would have to study the phisical caracteristics of the object (like you said throw a bucket and see what happens). Maybe it has a self-positioning caracteristic because of weight distribution. If not then you have to help position it correctly (vibratory feeders, conveyers,...) or think about adding another (or a few) camera.

Comment: Maybe you could even make an algorith to detect on which side it is positioned (like if it is on other side it has a smaller size or something like that). The issue would also be the lightning which can help and save a lot of time in writting your script (like coaxial diffused, o-rings, backlight,...).

Comment: all the things that you've mentioned assures me that its a multivariate image analysis if done in RGB. Rightnow I'm trying to align the largest axis of the contour to horizontal axis and take perpendicular distances from left to right, top and then bottom. I hope this may reveal a characteristic curve for those double curvature irrespective of what side they are on. Will keep you posted.

Comment: I am impressed with this solution !! plus 1

Comment: @Jeru Luke: Thanks...means a lot beacuse I have just started to learn.